# why is my image not displaying?

Tags: html, image, google-chrome, pug

I just changed the size of an png image in my website. I have changed the name and the url to it:

```
img(src='/images/newname.png')
```

I cleared the cache on chrome but the image still does not appear?

Comment: Does my answer make it work?

Comment: Have you tried visiting the image directly to verify that your path is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have written your code wrong. Here is the correct code:

```
<img src="/images/newname.png" alt="my image" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The path to the folder has to be relative to the html page this code is in. Right now you have the absolute path. (This is for pug / jade, not html by itself like the other answer)